# Is it a better way to get the inserted id in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, ognl, actionresult

I am using Hibernate 3.0 and Struts. I am using `@GeneratedValue` for the id generation.

I have one customer screen  when I save the customer details I want to move to the next screen with the 
newly inserted `customerId` because based on that ID only I will save the second page details

for that I am using like

```
someDAO.save(customer);
customerId = customer.getCustomerId();
```

I get the customer object value after save and using Struts 2 `redirectAction` I forward the `customerId` to second page,  it is working fine but I am getting warn on my console

```
Caught OgnlException while setting property 'applicationId' on type 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult'.
ognl.NoSuchPropertyException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletActionRedirectResult.applicationId
    at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:132)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlValueStack$ObjectAccessor.setProperty(OgnlValueStack.java:68)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.setProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1656)
    at ognl.ASTProperty.setValueBody(ASTProperty.java:101)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateSetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:177)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:246)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way You can ignore this,

However **redirectAction** uses the **ActionMapper** provided by the **ActionMapperFactory** to redirect the browser to a URL that invokes the specified action and (optional) **namespace**. The OGNL try to set the map html elements with values specified on source page and push these values in the **valuestack**. sometimes **OGNL** attempts to map values with setters which is specified in the action class with the source -page and failed to set the values and **resulted in warning**.

you can try explicitly assigning the **param's** to suppress warning :

```
<result name="showReportResult" type="redirectAction">
     <param name="applicationId">${applicationId}</param>
 </result>
```

Answer (score 1):

The exception says that

> Exception thrown if a property is attempted to be extracted from an
>   object that does not have such a property

This means that you need to the Java bean property `applicationId`. Putting getters and setters on the field should solve the issue.

About better way to insert the id with hibernate use

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
```